# Java - Encrypt String with existing public key file

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I've been researching this for the past 4-5 hours now and can't seem to find an answer that actually *works* despite finding 'answers' that used everything from a few methods to an entire ~100 line class. I can't imagine that there isn't some simple function to do such a trivial thing :P

I have a pre-existing set of public / private keys (actually, two sets - one generated by ssh-keygen and another by openssl so .. whatever format works is cool).

All I am after is a simple java equivalent to what I write in python like -

```
key_object = someModule.KeyObject(nameOfPublicKeyFile)

def encrypt (SomePlainText) :
  return someOtherModule.encrypt(key_object, SomePlainText)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

These openssl commands in the shell create an RSA key pair and write the public and private keys to **DER** formatted files.

*Here, the private key file is not password-protected (-nocrypt) to keep things simple.*

```
$ openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
............+++
................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
$ openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -outform DER -pubout -out public.der
writing RSA key
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

Now that you have the DER files, you can read them in Java and use **KeySpec** and **KeyFactory** to create **PublicKey** and **PrivateKey** objects.

```
public byte[] readFileBytes(String filename) throws IOException
{
    Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    return Files.readAllBytes(path);        
}

public PublicKey readPublicKey(String filename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(readFileBytes(filename));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);       
}

public PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String filename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(readFileBytes(filename));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);     
}
```

With the public and private keys, you can encrypt and decrypt small amounts of data (that fit within your RSA modulus.) I recommend **OAEP** padding.

```
public byte[] encrypt(PublicKey key, byte[] plaintext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");   
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
}

public byte[] decrypt(PrivateKey key, byte[] ciphertext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");   
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);  
    return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
}
```

Here it is tied together with a simple encryption and decryption:

```
public void Hello()
{
    try
    {
        PublicKey publicKey = readPublicKey("public.der");
        PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKey("private.der");
        byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] secret = encrypt(publicKey, message);
        byte[] recovered_message = decrypt(privateKey, secret);
        System.out.println(new String(recovered_message, "UTF8"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, only I get a java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format while reading the key file back to generate the key. I know it could be related to file format. What should i watch out for?

Comment: I am trying to use a pem file by the way.

Comment: @Merrin It might be that you have a PKCS#1 PEM "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" (note the "RSA") instead of PKCS#8 "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY". Check this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key

Comment: Great, Thanks, let me take a look.

Comment: Shouldn't you use private key for encryption and public key for decryption?

Comment: @Shmarkus No! https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/asymmetric.shtml `the key used for encryption is called the public key, and can be distributed freely;
the key used for decryption is called the private key, and must be kept a secret among parties that are allowed to decrypt messages encrypted with the public key`

Comment: Yep, the private key is used for signing and public for validation. That is where the confusion came from.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share a piece of code.. well actually a whole class which can do what you require if you customize it to your own needs. I have used this in one of my application where I used to encrypt/decrypt a file with the generated public/private keys. Same can be applied to Strings as well.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *  This class encrypts and decrypts a file using CipherStreams
 *  and a 256-bit Rijndael key. The key is then encrypted using
 *  a 1024-bit RSA key, which is password-encrypted.
 */
public class FileEncryptorRSA {
  /**
   *    When files are encrypted, this will be appended to the end
   *    of the filename.
   */
  private static final String ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX=".encrypted";

  /**
   *    When files are decrypted, this will be appended to the end
   *    of the filename.
   */
  private static final String DECRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX=".decrypted";

  /**
   *    Number of times the password will be hashed with MD5
   *    when transforming it into a TripleDES key.
   */
  private static final int ITERATIONS = 1000;

  /**
   *    FileEncryptor is started with one of three options:
   *
   *    -c: create key pair and write it to 2 files
   *    -e: encrypt a file, given as an argument
   *    -d: decrypt a file, given as an argument
   */
  public static void main (String[] args)
  throws Exception {
    if ((args.length < 1) || (args.length > 2)) {
      usage();
    } else if ("-c".equals(args[0])) {
      createKey();
    } else if ("-e".equals(args[0])) {
      encrypt(args[1]);
    } else if ("-d".equals(args[0])) {
      decrypt(args[1]);
    } else {
      usage();
    }
  }

  private static void usage() {
    System.err.println("Usage: java FileEncryptor -c|-e|-d [filename]");
    System.exit(1);
  }

  /**
   *    Creates a 1024 bit RSA key and stores it to
   *    the filesystem as two files.
   */
  private static void createKey()
  throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Password to encrypt the private key: ");
    String password = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("Generating an RSA keypair...");

    // Create an RSA key
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

    System.out.println("Done generating the keypair.\n");

    // Now we need to write the public key out to a file
    System.out.print("Public key filename: ");
    String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();

    // Get the encoded form of the public key so we can
    // use it again in the future. This is X.509 by default.
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

    // Write the encoded public key out to the filesystem
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilename);
    fos.write(publicKeyBytes);
    fos.close();

    // Now we need to do the same thing with the private key,
    // but we need to password encrypt it as well.
    System.out.print("Private key filename: ");
    String privateKeyFilename = in.readLine();

    // Get the encoded form. This is PKCS#8 by default.
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

    // Here we actually encrypt the private key
    byte[] encryptedPrivateKeyBytes =
    passwordEncrypt(password.toCharArray(),privateKeyBytes);

    fos = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFilename);
    fos.write(encryptedPrivateKeyBytes);
    fos.close();
  }

  /**
   *    Encrypt the given file with a session key encrypted with an
   *    RSA public key which will be read in from the filesystem.
   */
  private static void encrypt(String fileInput)
  throws Exception {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
    String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();

    // Load the public key bytes
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = fis.read()) != -1)
    {
      baos.write(theByte);
    }
    fis.close();

    byte[] keyBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    // Turn the encoded key into a real RSA public key.
    // Public keys are encoded in X.509.
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

    // Open up an output file for the output of the encryption
    String fileOutput = fileInput + ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX;
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream
    (new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));

    // Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    // Now create a new 256 bit Rijndael key to encrypt the file itself.
    // This will be the session key.
    KeyGenerator rijndaelKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Rijndael");
    rijndaelKeyGenerator.init(256);
    System.out.println("Generating session key...");
    Key rijndaelKey = rijndaelKeyGenerator.generateKey();
    System.out.println("Done generating key.");

    // Encrypt the Rijndael key with the RSA cipher
    // and write it to the beginning of the file.
    byte[] encodedKeyBytes= rsaCipher.doFinal(rijndaelKey.getEncoded());
    output.writeInt(encodedKeyBytes.length);
    output.write(encodedKeyBytes);

    // Now we need an Initialization Vector for the symmetric cipher in CBC mode
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(iv);

    // Write the IV out to the file.
    output.write(iv);
    IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    // Create the cipher for encrypting the file itself.
    Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);

    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, symmetricCipher);

    System.out.println("Encrypting the file...");

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileInput);

    theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = input.read()) != -1)
    {
      cos.write(theByte);
    }
    input.close();
    cos.close();
    System.out.println("File encrypted.");
    return;
  }

  /**
   *    Decrypt the given file.
   *    Start by getting the RSA private key
   *    and decrypting the session key embedded
   *    in the file. Then decrypt the file with
   *    that session key.
   */
  private static void decrypt(String fileInput)
  throws Exception {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Private Key to decrypt with: ");
    String privateKeyFilename = in.readLine();

    System.out.print("Password for the private key: ");
    String password = in.readLine();

    // Load the private key bytes
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFilename);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = fis.read()) != -1)
    {
      baos.write(theByte);
    }
    fis.close();

    byte[] keyBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    keyBytes = passwordDecrypt(password.toCharArray(), keyBytes);

    // Turn the encoded key into a real RSA private key.
    // Private keys are encoded in PKCS#8.
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

    // Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

    // Read in the encrypted bytes of the session key
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileInput));
    byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = new byte[dis.readInt()];
    dis.readFully(encryptedKeyBytes);

    // Decrypt the session key bytes.
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] rijndaelKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);

    // Transform the key bytes into an actual key.
    SecretKey rijndaelKey = new SecretKeySpec(rijndaelKeyBytes, "Rijndael");

    // Read in the Initialization Vector from the file.
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    dis.read(iv);
    IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(dis, cipher);

    System.out.println("Decrypting the file...");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileInput + DECRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX);

    // Read through the file, decrypting each byte.
    theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = cis.read()) != -1)
    {
      fos.write(theByte);
    }
    cis.close();
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Done.");
    return;
  }

  /**
   *    Utility method to encrypt a byte array with a given password.
   *    Salt will be the first 8 bytes of the byte array returned.
   */
  private static byte[] passwordEncrypt(char[] password, byte[] plaintext) throws Exception {

    // Create the salt.
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    Random random = new Random();
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    // Create a PBE key and cipher.
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    // Encrypt the array
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

    // Write out the salt, then the ciphertext and return it.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(salt);
    baos.write(ciphertext);
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }

  /**
   *    Utility method to decrypt a byte array with a given password.
   *    Salt will be the first 8 bytes in the array passed in.
   */
  private static byte[] passwordDecrypt(char[] password, byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {

    // Read in the salt.
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ciphertext);
    bais.read(salt,0,8);

    // The remaining bytes are the actual ciphertext.
    byte[] remainingCiphertext = new byte[ciphertext.length-8];
    bais.read(remainingCiphertext,0,ciphertext.length-8);

    // Create a PBE cipher to decrypt the byte array.
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");

    // Perform the actual decryption.
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(remainingCiphertext);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

***You will require to change Java policy of you JVM to Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction for using this code.
All related information regarding change in JAVA Policy can be found [HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)***

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example:

- http://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/rsa-encryption-example/

and there are many more.  (Google for "java encrypt RSA example" if this link breaks.)

---

> I can't seem to find an answer that actually works

Try the one linked above.  If it doesn't work, please follow up with an edit or comment to say what is going wrong.

> I can't imagine that there isn't some simple function to do such a trivial thing. :P

Well sorry, but your imagination must be broken :-)

In fact, it is not a trivial thing.  And it is made more difficult by the fact that Java is trying to support a wide range of crypto functionality and crypto technology stacks using a single unified API.